# Get a list of all available stock tickers from pandas_datareader.data.DataReader using 'Yahoo' as data source

Tags: yahoo

I'm using pandas_datareader.data.DataReader and I need to list every ticker available to fetch information from, using yahoo as data source.
Is there a method to list them?
I've been sent to this web https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener, but I want to do it within a python program. Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download that csv file using a GET request to url or with pandas directly into a DataFrame https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true

Alternatively, you can check some Python packages to get financial data from Yahoo! like the following:

- [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)
- [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/)

Comment: Do you need to have authentication to access the end-point in the long run?

Comment: Looks good, no authentication needed